# displaying json response from jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

My ajax call successfully returns data from a database, but I can't figure out how to parse the json and display it correctly. Here's my ajax call:

```
$('#cardText').change(function(){
            if($('#cardText').val().trim().length == 9)
                {
                    $.ajax({

                        url: 'components/Person.cfc',

                        //GET method is used
                        type: "POST",

                        //pass the data        
                        data: {
                            method: "getGroup",
                            uid: $('#cardText').val(),
                            },
                        datType: "json",

                        success: function(response) {

                            var resp = $.trim(response);
                            $('#form_result').html(resp);
                        },

                        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                                alert('Time out error.');
                            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                            } else {
                                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                            }
                        }
                }); 
            }
        });
```

And it returns the following to (div id="form_result") but I can't figure out what now to do with the data to display it correctly:

```
{"COLUMNS":["PLAN","NAME","ID","ISSUE","TYPE","LASTUSED","BALANCE"],"DATA":[["DINING STAFF CAFE 1919 ","YOUNG, MARIA ",8.03976343E8,"2001-04-02",2.0,"2012-01-27",1]]}
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Gerald

Comment: Do you want to create a table of it? What do you want with the data?

Comment: You have a typeo: `datType` should be `dataType`

Comment: @MestekWebmaster the `dataType` defaults to JSON, it's not the problem

Comment: Yep, just realized that they said they're getting the data back.  Fingers worked quicker than brain :)

Comment: What is the question again? You have the data, just use it for whatever you want. By the way, the first parameter to `success` is the response object, it's the data, that is, in your case, a valid JS object that you can iterate over.

Comment: Hey Wouter Konecny, Making a table would be great or making an array or structure... I just don't know any possibility. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @MestekWebmaster - Now that I fixed the type (dataType) I'm getting a JSON parse error... crud. You have any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Sounds like there is a problem in the format of the data returned.  I would check that data and run it through something like jsonlint.com to be sure it's valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're getting the JSON on the client side, you can either fed it to some JS plugin that understand that data, or display them yourself with a template engine.

A decent template engine is what you need.

check out http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/, http://handlebarsjs.com/ or https://github.com/leonidas/transparency

Comment: My vote for templating JS is google closure templates. https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/helloworld_js

Comment: @JuanMendes why does your vote go to google closure templates?

Comment: Because of how easy it is. I don't like the client-side templates that define templates in the HTML file, and parse the templates on the client. That makes it hard to reuse them across pages. Google closure templates runs a build step on your template file and it generates a JS function that you can call from your script to generate the HTML and easily reuse it across pages.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by parsing json data in this way

```
var ReturnedData = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

then you can access data just like a simple object and array i.e.

```
var Col1 = ReturnedData.COLUMNS[0];  // will provide you first COLUMN value i.e. "PLAN"
var Data1= ReturnedData.DATA[0];  // will provide you first DATA value i.e. "DINING STAFF     CAFE 1919"
```

above two lines are just an example that how you can grab your data

Comment: This seems like what I want, but after I fixed my typo in dataType, I'm now getting a parseerror -- am I doing the json correctly?

Comment: To find out the issue perform following steps. 1) observer your returned json format, a parsing error mostly occurs due to a malformed JSON 2) try JSON.parse(response) that is native function of jquery.parseJSON 3) apply a try catch and observer the error

Answer (score 0):

It appears you simply need to do something with the JSON data returned from the server. If you want to parse it into a more reasonable format, like a hash, see my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/skamansam/T7WbK/25/. If you simply want to tell the user the data he/she submitted was correct, change the line that reads:

`$('#form_result').html(resp);`

to

`$('#form_result').html("Form submitted successfully!");`

The ideal here is that you change your server response to something that makes sense, like an html response instead of json. This seems to be more of a question of preference, than technicality or protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is extra comma in "data"
Try removing comma after `uid: $('#cardText').val()`